# Extract required data between characters from a string using regex in python or pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to extract data between few characters from the string data present in the rows of a dataframe column.
For example I have the data in the column like below:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                               Azure|
+----------------------------------------------------+
|{ref=[As Tailwind Traders gets, started with Azure]}|
|{ref=first steps}                                   |
|{ref=will be to create}                             |
|{ref=at least one Azure subscription}               |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

**And want to transform in this way**

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                               Azure|
+----------------------------------------------------+
|As Tailwind Traders gets, started with Azure        |
|first steps                                         |
|will be to create                                   |
|at least one Azure subscription                     |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

So I should extract data between "[]" and also the the rows with single element and put it back into the same or a new column using pyspark/python regex
things to be removed - 'ref=',outer '{}'

***Note - I tried using the regex_replace function but it is also replacing the the [],{} inside the required data***

So how can I achieve this using regex in pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following pattern, putting \1 in the substitution string.

```
"{ref=\[?([,\w\s]+)\]?\}"gm
```

See https://regex101.com/r/OyFBkJ/1